# IdentityServer4 - redirect after registration

Tags: redirect, authorization, openid, identityserver4

I have a simple setup with IdentityServer4 (custom user store) and Mvc client app. Some pages in the client app are protected. So for example when a user hits /pageX he gets redirected to IdentityServer for authentication. This works fine when the user exists, he just logs in and gets redirected.
If he is not registered, he is asked to register and he gets an activation code via email.
Then he goes to inbox, clicks activation link and is invited to login again.
Now, after activation and login, I would like to redirect him to the /pageX he originally asked.
My problem is - at this point I no longer have a valid returnUrl which contains /pageX encoded somehow. I tried using the returnUrl which works in simple login flow:

returnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DmyClientIdt%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A5501%252Fsignin-oidc%26response_type%3Did_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26nonce%3D636469643044666440.MmZlNzFlMWYtZThhMS00ZjFlLTgyYjYtMDU5NjRmODBhZmNkMzk1MzJiZWItODY2Yy00NzYwLWE4YjQtOGU5YWU5Y2IxMDJk%26state%3DCfDJ8IK-YquShZdNsC5l0tQGkLIvU-_O1FbdO5RV9KrOZ9hCTixBZc-YeVLkKB2mvHkV9U42U83N7RfFCHywKjdbGRGnpfqwgG08_ip1Pt2sAqfa_sPlwYOO7fSiKUbnk2IpA1BMWvfeXNwIeFB7AMv0q0Y2z7vjCTNWawwNS6m5EM3h9V0uCpHE-1H19VPhE0OQcXmmcaNViWbdmWE14VNTH8MYQaPfE90smHtRwYtbYaYhfj-g4ziXbhN6m_R6PYni1ApazIDUBOowEq6yV9ynF91SM82gohud4Ek3juozL-A4W_dTIBZnj1C5PMmUISWl9yw_UPOvTwsCskVH2OmavgI%26x-client-SKU%3DID_NET%26x-client-ver%3D2.1.4.0)

But if I use this return url after registration, I get a correlation error message.

Any idea how can I return the user back to his original requested /pageX?

Answer (score 0):

The **returnUrl** (as sampled in the question) is a result of redirection from Authorize Endpoint to Login/Register Page. You need to use [IdentityServer Interaction Service](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/reference/interactionservice.html) to retrieve the actual returnUrl.

```
 var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
```

**context.RedirectUri** will hold the actual url (/PageX), where user needs to be redirected after activation.

You can pass **context.RedirectUri** as a query **parameter** to the activation **link** and retrieve it on the activation page. When activation is complete you can redirect the user to the **returnUrl**.

```
string activationLink = "<your activation url>?return=" + returnUrl;
```

Check this [docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/reference/interactionservice.html#authorizationrequest)

Comment: That's what I tried using that long returnUrl (sampled in the question). But that one gives me some error regarding correlation. I would like have returnUrl={clientapphost}/pageX, but can't see a way to get the /pageX in the identity server context.

Comment: @Andrei I have updated my answer to attempt to cover your queries.

Comment: I checked the context.RedirectUri value but that doesn't give me /pageX. It gives me something like:
http://localhost:5501/signin-oidc
which is I guess the talking back endpoint of the client app.

Comment: I'm curious, how does IdentityServer know to return to /pageX. I'm looking in debug mode at the context object but can't see any parameter or reference to /pageX. Encoded somewhere in the tokens used for chatting?

Answer (score 0):

Basically this situation can be avoided by not providing a link to click in the confirmation email which will land the user in a different browser tab.

Instead of a link provide an n-digit code in the email and let the user enter the code in the already open browser tab where you still have access to the returnUrl

Comment: And now you tell me :))
Anyway, I did solve it somehow. But from user perspective, might be more UX friendly to have a confirmation link. Clicking an activation link is easier than using code.